# javascript object load values as in C# dictionary (and pass it as a dictionary<string,string>)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I could see many of them questions the opposite direction

my question is how could i *pack* up values ?

```javascript
var KeyName = "name" or.. $(ControlId).attr("id")
var ValName = $(ControlId).val()
```

then with ajax post that value after of course serializing it (if it is required)

```javascript
var CS_Pckg = Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(DictionaryLike_Package);
ajaxPost(CS_Pckg);

...some ajax function
```

is it like an array ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has a "serialize" method that you can use for serialization of HTML forms: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

However, that method serializes to a GET string; if you instead want a set of name/value pair objects, checkout serializeArray: http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

If neither of those produces the output you want, you pretty much just have to do the serialization yourself.  You can use jQuery's each method to iterate through a set of elements, and then you can extract any information you want out of them.  Once you're done and you have a single Javascript object with all the data in it, you can convert that object to a string using `JSON.stringify(thatObject);`.

Here's a quick example:

```
var serializedData = {};
$('#yourForm').children().each(function(i, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    serializedData[$elem.attr('name')] = $elem.val();
});
alert("You're serialized JSON is: " + JSON.stringify(serializedData));
```

(No example for the earlier options, because they're as simple as `var serialized = $('#yourForm').children().serialize();`.)

Comment: i would appreciate a Code Sample as with my example , thanks @machineghost , as i am still fresh with jQuery ..

Comment: Your example dealt with a single value, and I imagine you want to serialize a whole form, so I geared my example towards that.  If you don't have a form with an ID on it you can replace the first `$('#yourForm').children()` part with any other jQuery selector (eg. `$('input').each(...` or `$('input').serialize()`).

Comment: thanks alot ! . does `JSON` requiers a download too ?, as a package like in `jQuery` & `jQuery UI` that's why i thought of working with standrt  arrays as in my example for serializing e.g `JavaScriptSerializer.serialize`

Comment: I'm not familiar with JavaScriptSerializer.serialize, but it looks to be Microsoft's version of JSON.stringify.  All modern browsers have JSON.stringify, and you can support old browsers that don't have it with a download from json.org.  In contrast, Microsoft stuff works ... in Microsoft-land (YMMV anywhere else).  Therefore personally I'd use the web-standard JSON.stringify.  If you <3 Microosft though it looks like you can just replace `JSON.stringify(` with `Sys.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.serialize(` and get the same result.

Comment: P.S. I'm pretty sure the "DictionaryLike_Package" that JavaScriptSerializer.serialize takes is just a standard Javascript object, ie. the "serializedData" variable in my example.

Comment: i guess i shouldn't avoid getting JSON in to the family of script tags imports (:

Comment: i will use your `each` with a condition , the condition will ask for specific controls , then on other screnarios.. if i will need any other form that i need it as a whole form i will use it as u said , thank you so much for your help !

Comment: That should totally work; you can use as many loops (or whatever else) as you need, as long as they all work with the same `serializedData` variable.  And you're welcome :-)